# enterprise library 2 and 3.1 side by side

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

We want to use the Enterprise Library 3.1 for logging into the eventlog, but our sub contractor uses EL 2.0 for similar purposes. Since we all run under a common executable, all the configuration data should be in the same .config file.
Is there a way to put in config sections for logging under 2.0 and under 3.1 in the same config file? I tried renaming the section ("loggingConfiguration3" instead of "loggingConfiguration"), but it didn't work. Is there some other way?

Comment: How about you both update to 4.1?  The update path is not that difficult.

Comment: We are stuck in vs2005 c# 2.0. Sadly no 4.1 for us.
And we can't ask our sub contractor to upgrade to 3.1 - politics.
I think I might just try using log4net, and avoid d the problem...

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a single configuration file they will not work side by side.

Two apps on the same machine with different configuration files and different versions of EntLib will work.

As JP says in the comment why not upgrade to 4.1. EntLib is backward compatible, should just be a case of copying in the latest dll's and updating the configuration file. The last times we have updated Entlib, has taken less than 1 hour, with no code changes needed.